# Add tag synonyms for [tag:community]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are a bunch of ways to say the concept behind [community](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/community). I was tagging a question and typed what I thought were plausible ways to express it (project, management, ubuntu-project, governance, maintainer), and it took many tries before I found [community](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/community). Because the name of our tag is non-obvious, it would help future taggers if we preemptively set up these as aliases.